# Ansible connects via WinRM but hangs on first step

Tags: ansible, packer

I am trying to use Packer, with Ansible as a provisioner, to build a Windows AMI.

`$ packer --version
   1.0.3`

`$ ansible --version
   ansible 2.2.0.0`

Ansible seems to connect successfully, but then hangs at the first step in the playbook, downloading 7zip. Below are my Packer template and a sample of the Ansible playook.

*Packer*

```
{
"builders": [{
    "type": "amazon-ebs",
    "region": "us-west-2",
    "source_ami": "ami-09f47d69",
    "instance_type": "m4.large",
    "ami_name": "Packer windows test",
    "user_data_file": "./scripts/ec2bootstrap.ps1",

    "communicator": "winrm",
    "winrm_username": "Administrator"
}],

"provisioners": [
    {
        "type": "powershell",
        "scripts": [
          "./scripts/ec2config.ps1",
          "./scripts/bundleconfig.ps1"
        ]
    },

    {
        "type": "ansible",
        "playbook_file": "../ansible/base_ami_site.yml",
        "extra_arguments": [
             "--connection", "packer",
             "--extra-vars", "ansible_shell_type=powershell ansible_shell_executable=None -vvvv"    
        ]

}]}
```

**Ansible sample**

```
- name: Download 7-Zip Installer
win_get_url:
url: http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1604-x64.msi
dest: C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\7-zip.msi
force: no
```

Just to reiterate, it does connect, but nothing runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out packer version `1.0.3` was preventing ansible from successfully being run.